# ContentProvider without SQL

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-contentprovider

I have two pieces of data that need to be accessed from outside applications and stored. According to documentation ContentProviders are the only possible way, but it also mentions external storage. ContentProviders implement a database-like "interface" and using a database would be extremely unnecessary for two pieces of data. I would rather save them to a file, but using a ContentProvider by implementing the abstract methods is problematic because the methods are structured as database queries.

I know that there is nothing specifying that ContentProviders must use a database underneath to store data, but is there any other way to store minimal amount of data that has to be shared to the file system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just used [`MatrixCursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor) to solve that exact problem. Take a look at it.

Edit: Sorry, I had just scanned the question when I answered it. `ContentProvider` is the only way for Applications to share data. Activities within an Application can use `SharedPreferences` for smaller data, with the addition of persistence.

Edit v2: Here's the function I used to populate a MatrixCursor for the query function of my ContentProvider. I am using a predefined VIEW I created that returns a set of distinct values, and this sets up a cursor with _ids that I can pass to my ExpandableListView.

```
private Cursor getFactions() {
        MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(Model.Faction.PROJECTION);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query(MODELFACTION_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { Model.Faction.FACTION }, null, null, null, null, Model.Faction.FACTION + " ASC");
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            mc.addRow(new Object[] { c.getPosition(), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Model.Faction.FACTION))});               
        } while (c.moveToNext() && ! c.isAfterLast());
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return mc;
    }
```

Comment: Well I need to share data between applications so I suppose I will need ContentProviders. The MatrixCursor does look promising because of the ability to store objects but I suppose the MatrixCursor needs to be backed by a DB somewhere yes?

Comment: Not at all! I just created the MatrixCursor, and added the elements. No db needed. When you instantiate a MatrixCursor, you provide a String[] of field names or column names, then just add the datasets or rows. Where you get that data from is completely up to you.

Comment: Ended up using a matrix cursor with standard file input/output underneath. Then reading the information by using ContentResolver.query () and storing it in a cursor. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The `SharedPreferences` class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use `SharedPreferences` to save any primitive data: **booleans**, **floats**, **ints**, **longs**, and **strings**. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed)

Useful links:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html